# HERE maps not showing untill selecting an option on "chosing view"

Tags: here-api

Here Maps have been working fine until a few days ago. Now they are blank and I get the following 3 errors in the console:

1. `Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://3.pano.maps.cit.api.here.com/maptile/2.1/rctile/4b09eb4445/terrain.day/14/2637/6355/256/jpg?xnlp=CL_JSMv3.0.17.0&app_id=MY_APP_ID&app_code=MY_APP_CODE. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).`
   (repeated several times)
2. Loading failed for the  with source “https://1.pano.maps.cit.api.here.com/maptile/2.1/copyright/4b09eb4445?xnlp=CL_JSMv3.0.17.0&app_id=MY_APP_ID&app_code=MY_APP_CODE&output=json&callback_func=H.service.jsonp.handleResponse(5)”.
   5144:1
3. `Error: [timeout]: Could not fetch copyrights from map tile service @https://1.pano.maps.cit.api.here.com/maptile/2.1/copyright/4b09eb4445?xnlp=CL_JSMv3.0.17.0&app_id=MY_APP_ID&app_code=MY_APP_CODE&output=json mapsjs-core.js%20line%2056%20%3E%20eval:22:406`

(I have masked MY_APP_ID and MY_APP_CODE).

**However**, if I switch to any option in the "Choose View" (eg terrain), the maps are displayed correctly.

Any idea?

Limits have not been reached

Answer (score 0):

Please replace Map Versions "4b09eb4445" to "newest".
Currently Here api has some trouble to support Hash Code for Map Version.

Comment: yup,  `H.Map(mapDiv, defaultLayers.terrain.panorama);` did not work, but `H.Map(mapDiv, defaultLayers.normal.map);` did. As of this morning both work.